# Ansible - Can I print information during module execution?

Tags: python, ansible

I would like to know if there is a way to print information while a module is executing -- primarily as a means to demonstrate that the process is working and has not hung. Specifically, I am trying to get feedback during the execution of the **cloudformation** module. I tried modifying the (Python) source code to include the following:

```
def debug(msg):
   print json.dumps({
      "DEBUG" : msg
   })

...

debug("The stack operation is still working...")
```

What this did, of course, was store all this output and only print it all after the module had finished executing. So for particularly large cloudformation templates, this means that I wait around for 5 minutes or so, and then suddenly see a large amount of text appear on the screen at the end. What I was expecting was to see "The stack operation is still working..." printed every x seconds.

It would seem that the [Asynchronous Actions and Polling](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_async.html) are what I'm looking for... but this didn't work, either. The entire task, "Launch CloudFormation for {{ stackname }}", was skipped entirely. See below for the relevant (YAML) snippet from my playbook:

```
- name: Launch CloudFormation for {{ stackname }}
      cloudformation: >
       stack_name="{{ stackname }}" state=present
       region="{{ region }}" disable_rollback=true
       template="{{ template }}"
      register: cloud
      args:
        template_parameters:
          KeyName: "{{ keyName }}"
          Region: "{{ region }}"
          SecurityGroup: "{{ securityGroup }}"
          BootStrapper: "{{ bootStrapper }}"
          BootStrapCommand: "powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File C:\\{{ bootStrapper }} {{ region }}"
          S3Bucket: "{{ s3Bucket }}"
      async: 3600
      poll: 30
```

This tells me that async is meant for typical shell commands, and not complex modules such as cloudformation. **OR** -- I may have done something wrong.

Could anyone shed some light on this situation? Again, for large cloudformation tasks that take a while, I would like some periodic indication that the task is still running, and not hanging. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple - no.
Ansible is a Continuous system that aims to handle ability to run over a bunch of servers and displaying real-time stdout results can be very unconvenient.

But I think You can use some tricks if Your destination system can support execution in background. I see that Your system is windows, so You have to install cygwin onto it for ability to run background commands like "sleep 20 &" in the example below

You can run this playbook with `ansible-playbook -vv background.yml`
You can see that stdout changing. 
`echo Test---- >> /tmp/test && tail /tmp/test` is a demo command. You should output data to some file and tail it for ability to see the progress. Or You may look at file size of stdout file and display it. Use imagination )))

```
# @file background.yml

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Background operation
    shell: "sleep 20 & \ PPID=$! \ echo $PPID"
    register: bcktsk

  - name: Check PPID
    shell: "kill -0 {{ bcktsk.stdout | int + 2 }}"
    register: checkppid
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Check if process still active
    shell: "echo Test---- >> /tmp/test && tail /tmp/test && kill -0 {{ bcktsk.stdout | int + 2 }}"
    register: test
    when: checkppid.rc == 0
    until: test.rc ==1
    delay: 2
    retries: 10000
    ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: Thank you. I can at least do something like this to report on maybe a 30-second interval a simple note "The operation is still working...". It's just a shame that Ansible doesn't support true asynchronous processes yet.

Comment: Although in practice, this doesn't seem to work for the CloudFormation module. Again, it appears only simple shell commands can execute asynchronously (or as background processes.) **So the answer is still a concrete NO.**

Answer (score 11):

My approach for localhost module:

```
...
module.log(msg='test!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
...
```

Then on another window:

```
 $ tail -f /var/log/messages

 Nov 29 22:32:44 nfvi-ansible-xxxx python2: ansible-test-module test!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: with module.warn('message') it is only visible once

Answer (score 1):

There is a way around this, and it will display real-time output, however you'll have to deal with injected prefixes on each line.  It's messy/hackish but for debugging/monitoring purposes it gets the job done:

```
- name: Run some command and echo it's realtime stdout
  shell: ":"
  with_lines: "/usr/bin/some_long_running_command with arguments and such here"
```

The command `:` is just a noop, you can easily use `command: /usr/bin/true` if that's easier.  In any case, this will output lines similar to:

```
changed: [localhost] => (item=first output line)
changed: [localhost] => (item=second output line)
changed: [localhost] => (item=third output line)
```

Comment: this is wrong: it works only on 'localhost' not on remote machines

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to run a shell command in background and print the output (partly based on podarok's answer above). Provide the command to be executed in the background_shell_command variable, and run as playbook or using include_tasks:

```
---

- name: Run shell command in background
  shell: "({{ background_shell_command }}>/tmp/background_task_output 2>&1; echo $? > /tmp/background_task_return_code) & echo $!"
  register: background_task

- name: check if background task has finished
  debug:
    var: "lookup('pipe','tr \"\\r\" \"\\n\"</tmp/background_task_output | tail -1')"
  retries: 10000000
  delay: 1
  until: "{{ lookup('pipe','ps -p {{ background_task.stdout | int }} >>/dev/null 2>&1 && echo false || echo true') }}"

- name: check return value of background task
  shell: "cat /tmp/background_task_return_code"
  register: background_task_exit_code

- name: fail if background task has failed
  fail:
    msg: "Error: the background command '{{ background_shell_command }}' has failed with return code {{ background_task_exit_code.stdout | int }}"
  when: background_task_exit_code.stdout | int != 0
```